# Determining distribution of temperature inside a sphere by distribution on its surface.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose we have smooth function (for example temperature) defined on sphere. We know everything about its behaviour on its surface.

> Does this determines all the values inside sphere? If so, what the formula looks like? If don't ,how the values generally behaves?

I strongly belive that it determines because it works on complex plane in form of Cauchy integral formula. One can just modify it and the result schould follows.

Comment: Do you consider a real sphere? $S^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Yes i do. Will Laplace equation help?

Comment: I’m not sure how the Cauchy integral formula will help you there. In this regard, complex and real domains are very different

Answer (score 1):

On a real (unit) sphere $\mathbb{S}^2 \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ hardly anything can be said. Consider the constant scalar field $f(x) =1$ and $g(x,y,z) = (x^2,y^2,z^2)$.